# Build maven modules from parent without parent reference

Tags: maven, tycho

I have set up a reactor build for several modules which works nicely. My submodules do not reference the parent pom.

As I use my submodules for several products there exist multiple parent poms, so I cannot put a parent reference to the submodules anyway.

Now I want the parent pom to be able to change some settings in the submodules. How can this be achieved without referring to a parent pom?

It would be great to have some default values defined in the submodule pom which might be overruled by the parent.

Comment: Values in the parent are overridden by the child. Its more like Java or C# and not like Ant in that regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a parent POM reference, you cannot inherit from the parent POM. This is by design: To ensure reproducibility, the model of the build shall be computable from the POM of a module.

The only additional sources of configuration for a Maven build are the `settings.xml` and the command line. So as a workaround, you may be able to build the same sources twice with different properties set on the command line.

Comment: While this answer is what I expected, I'd like to refine my question, maybe there exists another way to achieve my goal:
My submodule is an eclipse plugin which might be built for 32 or 64 bit. This depends on the product where it should go to. So I have multiple product poms (parent poms) defining either 64 or 32 bit. According to your answer I would have to use command line parameters when calling the parent pom, is this correct?

Comment: If you insist on building different things from the same sources, yes.

Answer (score 1):

> It would be great to have some default values defined in the submodule pom which might be overruled by the parent.

That is called [Maven inheritance](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance). But as with Java, only 1 pom can be parent of the current module. There may be inheritance hierarchies, but that would made project even more complicated.

In one of my big projects, I ended up with parent pom with base settings, and every module referencing current version (SNAPSHOT).  ( I played with module referencing previous explicit version, that was confusing. ) That made life easier, and quicker to evolve.

And then of course every module can overwrite some settings.