# Failed to read artifact descriptor for library

Tags: maven, artifactory

I have a multi module maven project, where one of the modules should be a shared resource published to artifactory. I only publish that given module (mvn -B deploy -pl [module name])

The artifact is successfully created and published, but if I try to pull it in from an another project, it fails with

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor
```

as it cannot find the parent pom published.

Is there any way to build this module as a standalone one pulling in whatever it needs and not referring to the parent to avoid this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589876/build-maven-modules-from-parent-without-parent-reference

Comment: Thank you both, these set me to the right direction. The final solution was to remove the parent from the child pom, move all necessary dependencies there but keep the child as a module of parent for the build.